# My loginButtons widget is asking for email even though I'm declaring it should ask for a username

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Hey guys I have a meteor app that I'm just starting and I don't understand why it's still asking for an email instead of a username, even though I have

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
});
```

in the client side.

The HTML just has `{{> loginButtons}}`, and when I click it when I run the app on localhost, it asks for email. I have the `accounts-ui` and `accounts-password` packages installed.

Comment: any error in console? small reporduction of issue in meteorpad.com wil help to assist better.

Comment: Is the code specified above located in a file that is only loaded on the client?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was the location in which I put the Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
});

I moved it to the top of the client side js file and it worked perfectly